# biginteger calculation problem

Tags: java

I am using the following code but the parameters are not passed to the methods.

```
BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
BigInteger u1 = obj.bigi_calc(g1, l);
```

In this g1,l are long values.

The method is

```
private BigInteger bigi_calc(long g1, long l){           

        BigInteger cal = BigInteger.valueOf(g1);
        BigInteger cal1= BigInteger.valueOf(l);
        for(BigInteger f = BigInteger.ONE;f.compareTo(cal1)>0;f=f.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
            //BigInteger p= BigInteger.valueOf(0);
            p = cal.multiply(cal1);
            System.out.println("check p"+p);
        }
    //  System.out.println("check p"+p);
        return p;
    }
```

The elipse shows that it may be out of sync, but the parameters are not passed to the functions.
Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare `BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(0);` as a local variable outside of `bigi_calc`? Because in that case, then the scope of `p` does not extend to the method `bigi_calc`.

You may either want to:

- Pass `p` as a third argument
- Make it a member field

To do the first option, you'd do something like this:

```
private BigInteger bigi_calc(long g1, long l, BigInteger p) { ... }

//...
BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
BigInteger u1 = obj.bigi_calc(g1, l, p);
```

---

Examining the code further reveals that it doesn't make any sense. There is a [`BigInteger.pow`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) if that's what you're trying to compute. And using a `BigInteger` for a loop counter when it's not going to exceed a `long` is just unnecessary clutter.

If `pow(long base, long exp)` is what you want, and for some reason you aren't allowed to use `BigInteger.pow`, then you can write it like this:

```
static BigInteger pow(long base, long exp){              
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger biBase = BigInteger.valueOf(base);
    for (long i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
        result = result.multiply(biBase);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for faster exponentiation but unless this is homework you should just use `BigInteger.pow`